# Open one key value at a time with click event Angular 8

Tags: angular

I have an object and I am trying to set up (eventually) the capacity to edit each key value in that object by opening a form with a toggle and editing that property via a small form.

I have tried using a key pipe, but the data is structured differently for each k:v, as there is quite a lot of relational stuff going on with different tables. I applied this, thinking that I could then index the k:v and thus, open each based on its index. Maybe I should look into this more?

To start with, I need to get the toggle(`*ngIf"=show_form" | openForm()`) to work, as currently if I click one button to show that k:v, all the buttons open as the condition is set to true across the board.

**This is a simplistic view of the HTML:**

```
<li>App Body Font Family:</li>
<ul>
    <li>{{ config.body_font.data.font_family }}<li>
    <li><button (click)="openForm('body)">{{ button_text }}</button>
    <ng-container *ngIf="show_form">
        <li *ngIf="fonts">
        <span *ngFor="let font of fonts">
        {{ font.font_family }}//form will live here eventually as a select dropdown
        </span>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
<li>App Headings Font Family:</li>
<ul>
    <li>{{ config.header_font.data.font_family }}<li>
    <li><button (click)="openForm('header')">{{ button_text }}</button>
    <ng-container *ngIf="show_form">
        <li *ngIf="fonts">
        <span *ngFor="let font of fonts">
        {{ font.font_family }}//form will live here eventually as a select dropdown
        </span>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
public show_form: any = {
    body: false,
    header: false
}

public openForm(key: any) {
    this.show_form[key] = !this.show_form[key]
}
```

as you can see `show_form` will be set to true when the button is clicked and so currently both sections open and close not just the one I've clicked.

I'm suffering from a little dev burnout so the problem to a clearer mind might be pretty obvious. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're going to need to keep track of which form to show, which you could do by `k`

Comment: I had a feeling that might need to happen. I'm currently just binding the object without a *ngFor loop. I'll need to re-write this to bind from the object key rather than as is. Or do you see that this could be done without a loop?

Comment: It depends on the number of objects you're binding and how much work you're wanting to do. At the end of the day, all you need is a single view model property that holds which form is to be shown. If whatever value in your object matches that value, then display your form. You don't need to maintain an object or an array to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `show_form` as an object of all titles (or anything else that is unique)

Typescript:

```
public show_form: any= {
    title:false,
    title2:false
};

public openForm(title:any) {
   this.show_form[title] = !this.show_form[title]
   ...
}
```

Template:

`<li><button (click)="openForm('title')">{{ button_text }}</button>`

`<li><button (click)="openForm('title2')">{{ button_text }}</button>`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show_form['title']">
  ...
</ng-container>


<ng-container *ngIf="show_form['title2']">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. I will also give this a go.

Comment: Hi @Adrita - tried this, but show_form is always set to true on page load and doesn't close when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: I'll edit my question, as there is quite a bit of API dependency going on here

Comment: You have to modify `<ng-container *ngIf="show_form['title']">` this part as well. I forgot to mention it before :)

Comment: that's the one! Brilliant. Thank you.